# In Rally, Using Java REST API, How to get the complete list of test cases present in all sub-folders of a TestPlan folder?

Tags: rally

In query filter, i have tried with FormattedID, TestFolder.Parent.Name, TestFolder.Name. 
Here TestFolderID can be a TestPlan folder name OR any parent folder with subfolders. With below code, I am getting only the test cases directly present in the folder, but not from all subfolders of a given folder name.

```
            TestFolderID="TF27980";
            QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest("TestCases");
            queryRequest.setFetch(new Fetch(new String[] {"Name", "TestCases","FormattedID","TestFolder"}));

            queryRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef.get());
            queryRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("TestFolder.Parent.Name", "=",  TestFolderID) );

            queryRequest.setScopedDown(true);
            queryRequest.setLimit(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            queryRequest.setPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

            QueryResponse queryResponse = null;
            JsonArray jsonarr = new JsonArray();
            queryResponse = restApi.get().query(queryRequest);
            int responseTotalResultsCount = queryResponse.getTotalResultCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to populate the entire tree in one request.  The best you can do is probably to fetch the Descendants collection- that will give you both the TestFolder and the TestCase children for a certain test folder.  Then you can recursively continue down the tree.